# How to find difference between current date row and previous date row per each group?

Tags: python, date

i have like this data frame

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| a | 20-01-2020 |
| a | 22-03-2020 |
| a | 15-03-2020 |
| b | 05-02-2019 |
| b | 09-05-2019 |

- make loop to data frame
- in each row per (id) group except first row in group, compute difference between date[i] and date[i-1] if result <30 or >56, put in 'status' column "no"
- else the 'status' in this row be "yes"
  -the output data frame must be:

| id | date | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 20-01-2020 |  |
| a | 20-03-2020 | yes |
| a | 15-04-2020 | no |
| b | 05-02-2019 |  |
| b | 09-05-2019 | no |

Comment: You have basically written the algorithm out in your question, just change the three bullet points into code.

Comment: i use this condition in loop but not work,, if ((df['date'][i]-df['date'][i]-1)>65.0)                     
      df["status"][i]="no"

Comment: invalid syntax appear

Comment: `df['date'][i]-1` should be `df['date'][i-1]`. Perhaps, it would be easier if you added the code to the question, so we can see what you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) #in case of you didn't set it as datetime.

df['status'] = pd.Series(np.nan)
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if (df['date'][i]-df['date'][i-1]).days < 30 or (df['date'][i]-df['date'][i-1]).days > 56:
        df['status'][i] = 'no'
    else:
        df['status'][i] = 'yes'
print(df)
```

the output is:

```
  id       date status
0  a 2020-01-20    NaN
1  a 2020-03-22     no
2  a 2020-03-15     no
3  b 2019-05-02     no
4  b 2019-09-05     no
```

Comment: KeyError: -1   get this error, how to solve it

Comment: could you share the full error mesage? in which line it gives this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shift` to calculate difference between the rows and replace with your values based on the condition

```
df['status'] = (df['date'] - df['date'].shift()).dt.days
df['status'][df['status'].notnull()] = ((df['status'] < 30) | (df['status'] > 65)).replace({True: 'No', False: 'Yes'})
df = df.fillna('') # if you want to replace the first value with an empty string
```

Output

```
  id       date status
0  a 2020-01-20       
1  a 2020-03-22    Yes
2  a 2020-04-15     No
3  b 2019-02-05     No
4  b 2019-05-09     No
```